# Python: How to check if a set of coordinates in an array exists within a list within many dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python

Sorry if that sounds extremely confusing, but basically I've got a two column array storing a list of 2D coordinates:

```
array([[ 0.31730234,  0.73662906],
   [ 0.54488759,  0.09462212],
   [ 0.07500703,  0.36148366],
   [ 0.33200281,  0.04550565],
   [ 0.3420866 ,  0.9425797 ],
   [ 0.36115391,  0.16670599],
   [ 0.95586938,  0.52599398],
   [ 0.13707665,  0.6574444 ],
   [ 0.77766138,  0.56875582],
   [ 0.79618595,  0.7139309 ]])
```

I've got a list of dictionaries and in each of these dictionaries there is a list of random combinations of these coordinates under a key called 'coordinates'.

How do I make a function that, if a random set of coordinates is given, checks if these coordinates are present in any of the dictionaries, and then returns the index of the dictionary its present in?

Obviously the arguments are the list of dictionaries (since I actually have multiple lists of them) and the coordinate id in the array. Every time I try something with the any function or enumerate or find, I get syntax errors - e.g.:

```
def whichcluster(list,coordinate_id):
.....:     for elem in list:
.....:         if any(x in elem['coordinates'] for coordinate_id):
.....:             return list.index(elem)
.....:         else:
.....:             return False
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Could you explain your intent a little further please. It might help to figure out the most efficient solution. Do you only wish to return the index of the first matching cluster or all?

Answer (score 2):

Four Issues with your code

- Your generator expression feeding to any is wrong. It should be `any(x in elem['coordinates'] for x in coordinate_id)`
- You don;t need to use list.index(elem), to get the index but rather while looping use the enumerate function to get the index with the element `for index, elem in enumerate(list):
- Using a return inside a loop `return list.index(elem)` would prematurely return with the first hit. You may miss any subsequent matches. You need to create a generator
- Don;t use a reserved/in-build names for variable names, for example instead of `list`, use something more appropriate like `coord_list`

Answer (score 1):

You comprehension is written wrong, it should be:

```
if any(x in elem['coordinates'] for x in coordinate_id):
    ...
```

And `list` is a typename, don't use it as a variable name.